# Resolvent set/operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Just a question here. Why do we study Resolvent operators and resolvent sets? Will there be any motivation or intuition behind this?

Comment: For bounded operators, the resolvent set is merely the complement of the spectrum. So, the resolvent set is as important as the spectrum!

Comment: The resolvent is of paramount importance in the mathematical study of operators, in particular Schrödinger operators. Have a look at the four volumes Methods of modern mathematical physics by Reed and Simon. They are full of resolvents.

Comment: The resolvent is a holomorphic operator-valued function defined on an open domain, and holomorphic functions are nice. Loosely speaking, holomorphic functions are determined by their singularities, which turns into a study of spectrum. And, if the resolvent can be represented in terms of its boundary information on the spectrum, then quite often that leads to a decomposition related to the operator with a sum that is complete; this is because the residue at infinity is commonly $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\lambda\frac{1}{\lambda I -A} = I$, leading to sums of operator singularities = I.

Comment: @TrialAndError: Great comment!! :) ...so looking forward to studying analytical behavior of resolvents. :D

Comment: @TrialAndError: Finally, that also explains the importance of the spectrum over the resolvent set: The boundary of the resolvent set being part of the spectrum contains already alot of information about the operator itself.